# spark .txt Kafka message to Data Frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am getting error `CDRS.toDF()` error

```
case class CDR(phone:String, first_type:String,in_out:String,local:String,duration:String,date:String,time:String,roaming:String,amount:String,in_network:String,is_promo:String,toll_free:String,bytes:String,last_type:String) 

// Create direct Kafka stream with brokers and topics
//val topicsSet = Set[String] (kafka_topic)
val topicsSet = Set[String] (kafka_topic)
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> 
kafka_broker)
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, 
StringDecoder](
ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet).map(_._2)
//===============================================================================================

//Apply Schema Of Class CDR to Message Coming From Kafka
val CDRS = messages.map(_.split('|')).map(x=> CDR 

   (x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5),x(6),x(7),x(8),x(9),x(10),x(11),x(12),x(13).repla ceAll("\n","")))
```

Comment: case class CDR(phone:String, first_type:String,in_out:String,local:String,duration:String,date:String,time:String,roaming:String,amount:String,in_network:String,is_promo:String,toll_free:String,bytes:String,last_type:String)

Comment: It is a `DStream` and `DStreams` have no `toDF` method. Compilation error is expected. And if you want to add some information to your question, don't use comments. Just follow [edit] link.

Comment: Thank you. can you please refer me link. how can i convert DStream to RDD and To Data Frame ?

Comment: You cannot. You can `dstream.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.toDF)` but it looks like you're really looking for [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

Comment: Thank YOu. you said Right. i have converted to D Stream to foreachRDD and Then converted .toDf()